# What does javac.exe do when compile a .java file?

Tags: java, compilation, jvm, javac, bytecode

In my mind, what javac.exe does is like:

> .java->blackbox->.class

I'm trying to read the openJDK, but I don't quite understand the processes of how the blackbox works. So, I want to first analyze some examples then go deep into the openJDK again.

E.g.:

```
  public class Choices {
  static class C {}
  static class Java{}

    public static class Tom {
      public void hardChoice(C c) {
        System.out.println("Tom choose c");
      }
      public void hardChoice(Java java) {
        System.out.println("Tom choose java");
      }
    }

    public static class Tommy extends Tom {
      public void hardChoice(C c) {
        System.out.println("Tommy choose c");
      }
      public void hardChoice(Java java) {
        System.out.println("Tommy choose java");
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Tom tom = new Tom();
      Tom tommy = new Tommy();
      tom.hardChoice(new C());       // mark1
      tommy.hardChoice(new Java());  // mark2
    }
  }
```

When I put the code above into the javac.exe, in correspondence with mark1 and mark2, I will get two invokevirtual opcodes with the parameters, in bytecode, ***Method Choices$Tom.hardChoice:(LChoice$C;)V*** and ***Method Choices$Tom.hardChoice:(LChoice$java;)V***, respectively.

> Q: What ***processes*** will the two lines (***mark1 and mark2 in java
>   code***) will going through to become ***two invokevirtual*** methods
>   and some related bytecodes.

Comment: I think the compiler is open source you can read all of it. search for "grepcode Java compiler" or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Javac first parses and typechecks the program. Assuming these steps pass, the program is valid and will have a representation in Java bytecodes. Javac generates these bytecodes. Essentially ifs and loops are converted to use jumps; since Java bytecode has an operand stack translation of expressions is very direct. The bytecodes are a form of assembly code, except that they were not intended to match any real machine. Real hardware that executes Java bytecodes has since been built.

In the Java paradigm, the virtual machine is supposed to do pretty much all code optimization, so most implementations of javac do not perform code optimization.

Answer (score 2):

***I am primarily a C++ programmer, but I've looked into Java's bytecode out of curiosity. Here's what we do in C++:***

[image: http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Images/compile.png]

***This is what happens in Java:***

[image]

Although I am not really a Java programmer, it appears that compiling java into .class code works a lot like C or C++. Java compiles your code into **Java bytecode**, which is something like **general assembly instructions** that can easily be **interpreted or further compiled** into machine-specific processing instructions.

In other words, javac.exe compiles your code into a sort of **"general machine code"** that can later be translated into many different, specific types of machine code that work on only certain types of processors. This is why Java is so diverse--it's standard bytecode allows somebody to create a "translator/parser" to turn Java bytecode into their own machine's special machine instructions.